# Try-Catch statement doesn't "abort" function when reached an exception

Tags: c#, exception, naudio

This code has been working just fine for ages, but now suddenly started to do this crazy thing where sometimes, the code fails and crashes the program even though my code is inside a try-catch statement. Here's the code which fails:

```
try
{
audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(file); // here's where Im getting the exception
waveOut = new WaveOutEvent();
FadeInOut = new FadeInOutSampleProvider(audioFileReader);
waveOut.Init(new SampleToWaveProvider(FadeInOut));
PlaySource = Filetype.MP3;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
OnError.Invoke(e);
PostError(e);
}
```

And here's the exception I'm getting:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in NAudio.dll
>
> Additional information: Got a frame at sample rate 48000, in an MP3 with sample rate 44100. Mp3FileReader does not support sample rate changes.

Why isn't the code jumping down to the "catch" part but instead crashing?

Comment: have you certain if the error not in the `catch` statement ? (OnError.Invoke or PostError methods)

Comment: @Tokfrans, are you checking it in the debugger ?

Comment: A tip: press Ctrl + Alt + E to open the Exceptions window. Choose `Thrown` under `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`. All exceptions will be shown in the debugger directly where they happen, not higher up where they are handled.

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob Yes, I tried removing those lines from the catch but no change.

Comment: @gunr2171 Ah, I checked everything in the list, and then pressed OK. Every other exception also crashed the program then. So I unchecked and resetted, now it gets handled by my program again, including the one I described in the initial post. Weird that it somehow started to break on that exception.. Anyway; thank you :)

Comment: @Tokfrans, checking the box will not "break" your program, it will just raise awareness of the exceptions being thrown in your program. You can hit F5 to continue running the program, and if your code properly handles exceptions, then it will continue to run.

Comment: @gunr2171 I feel really stupid.. Why didn't I think about that!

Answer (score 2):

@Tokfrans - because it's not your code throwing the exception.

- Go to Tools/Options/Debugging and turn off "Enable Just My code (Managed only)". or option.
- Go to Debugger/Exceptions and turn off "User-unhandled" for Common-Language Runtime Exceptions.